# How do I read a function from one Jython script in another?

Tags: python, jython, function

me again,

I am trying to call a function from one Jython script to another and use it in another function in the 2nd script, let me expain.

I have a script `Tools.py` which includes in it several functions that I wish to use. For the moment I want to call the `run_prog()` function from `Tools.py` in the `prog()` function in a second script `Prog.py`.

I have looked through the forums and used:

```
from Tools import run_prog()
```

before the `prog()` function in the second script and got the error message:

```
No module named Tools
```

and

```
execfile(direc+"Tools.py")
```

and

```
os.system(direc+"Tools.py")
```

in the `prog()` function, but I get the error message:

```
global name 'run_prog()' is not defined
```

Can someone show me where I'm going wrong? The confusing part is that both `.py` scripts are in the same directory.

Possibly, for more clarity here's the breakdown of the scripts:

`Tools.py`

```
def run_prog():
    ...

def run_prog2():
    ...

def convert_image():
    ...

def read_image():
    ...
```

Now in `Prog.py`

```
def prog():
    run_prog()
    ...
```

Thanks,

Mr Kid

Comment: Well guys it doesn't look like this is getting fixed anytime soon, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from .Tools import run_prog
```

Never put brackets after the function's name when you import.

[**EDIT**] To make your Tools become a package, you should create a folder named `Tools`, rename your `Tools.py` into `__init__.py` and put it inside that folder.

Comment: I still get the error with no brackets after:

    Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: I still get the same error message after creating the new folder and renaming Tools.py *and moved it inside the Tools folder

Comment: You must move `__init__.py` inside the folder. Folder's name becomes module's name.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Prog.py` cannot find `Tools.py`. Normally (I mean in regular python) modules that are located in the same directory in your script will be found automatically.

What is your directory layout?

As a workaround you can use `jython -Dpython.path=foo/path:bar/path` to define an explicit search path.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this, they are in the same directory, which is what is confusing me.

Comment: So what happens if you open an interactive session and type `import Tools`?